# Flexbox not aligning item anymore when text is wrapped

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm struggeling with using a `flexbox` containter together with `bootstrap 4` to align my elements horizontally centered.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
    <img class="rounded-circle" height="50">
    <a href="https://some.external.link" target="_blank">
        Follow me
        <i class="fa fa-external-link "/>
    </a>
</div>
```

This works fine if the anchor's text is not wrapping. However, if it does the link-text is not centered anymore. Instead it goes left-alinged.

I already tried every possible combination on the container as well as using item-wrappers for the image and the anchor. Still the issue when link-text is wrapped.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you show us your css code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `text-center` as well, so the text in `a` will center.

The reason is, when the text gets too wide, so does the `a` element, and the `align-items-center` center the element, not its content.

So what happens is that the `a` grows until it reach its parent's width, and then the text will wrap, left aligned, as that is the default for text/content.

The `text-center` can be either added to the `div`'s class list (as it is inherited by the `a`), or on the `a` itself (done in the 2nd sample).

*In below two samples I added a border so you can see the difference.*

Stack snippet

```css
a {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center">
    <img class="rounded-circle" height="50">
    <a href="https://some.external.link" target="_blank">
        Follow me
        <i class="fa fa-external-link "/>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
    <img class="rounded-circle" height="50">
    <a href="https://some.external.link" target="_blank" class="text-center">
        Follow me Follow me Follow me Follow me Follow me Follow me Follow me Follow me Follow me Follow me Follow me Follow me         <i class="fa fa-external-link "/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working. Thanks. But I don't get the point why non-wrapped content is centered but wrapped not

Comment: @KingKerosin Check the update...better explained now

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox styles affects only direct children of the flex parent, in your situation it's `img` and `a`, but as soon as you wrap text inside `a`, flex can't affect this wrapper-element any more, cause it's not a direct children of the flex container. So if you want to wrap link text, add a class for centering text to the `a` element directly.